# Como atualizar um <select> com dados vindos de outro <select>

Tags: php, html, sql, select

Gostaria de saber como faço para atualizar um `select` com os dados vindos de outro.

Atualmente utilizo SQL, já tenho uma conexão criada:

```
$connection = new COM("ADODB.Connection"); //instancia a classe de conexao
$connection->Open("PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ADM;User ID=userxxx; Password=userxxx"); //estabelece conexão com MSSQL
```

---

```
<select>
  <option value="01">Empresa Construção</option>
  <option value="02">Empresa Prod Beleza</option>
  <option value="03">Empresa agricola</option>
  <option value="04"selected>Empresa comida</option>
</select>
```

Queria que, ao selecionar uma das empresas (por exemplo "Empresa Construção"), automaticamente buscasse no meu banco as informações da tabela e retornasse preenchendo a debaixo automaticamente, com as informações referente apenas a esta empresa.

```
<select>
  <option value="01">Tintas</option>
  <option value="02">madeira</option>
  <option value="03">Cimento</option>
  <option value="04"selected>Pedra</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Você vai fazer isso com ajax, no evento de change do primeiro select você executa o ajax pega os dados e joga no segundo select.

Comment: Desculpa, sou novo nisso e não entendi muito bem, não cheguei a executar nada com Ajax

Comment: Lê esse artigo: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started